# Pandas str.contains for exact matches of partial strings

Tags: python, regex, pandas, contains

I have a DataFrame (I'll call it `test`) with a column containing file paths and I want to filter the data using a partial path.

```
                              full_path
0    C:\data\Data Files\BER\figure1.png
1    C:\data\Data Files\BER\figure2.png
2    C:\data\Previous\Error\summary.png
3        C:\data\Data Files\Val\1x2.png
4        C:\data\Data Files\Val\2x2.png
5         C:\data\Microscopy\defect.png
```

The partial path to find is:

```
ex = 'C:\\data\\Microscopy'
```

I've tried `str.contains` but,

```
test.full_path.str.contains(ex)

0    False
1    False
2    False
3    False
4    False
5    False
```

I would have expected a value of `True` for index 5.  At first I thought the problem might be with the path strings not actually matching due to differences with the escape character, but:

```
ex in test.full_path.iloc[5]
```

equals `True`.   After some digging, I'm thinking the argument to `str.contains` is supposed to be a regex expression so maybe the "\"s in the partial path are messing things up?

I also tried:

```
test.full_path.apply(lambda x: ex in x)
```

but this gives `NameError: name 'ex' is not defined`.  These DataFrames can have a lot of rows in them so I'm also concerned that the `apply` function might not be very efficient.

Any suggestions on how to search a DataFrame column for *exact* partial string matches?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass `regex=False` to avoid confusion in the interpretation of the argument to `str.contains`:

```
>>> df.full_path.str.contains(ex)
0    False
1    False
2    False
3    False
4    False
5    False
Name: full_path, dtype: bool
>>> df.full_path.str.contains(ex, regex=False)
0    False
1    False
2    False
3    False
4    False
5     True
Name: full_path, dtype: bool
```

(Aside: your `lambda x: ex in x` should have worked.  The NameError is a sign that you hadn't defined `ex` for some reason.)

Comment: Thank you DSM!  I should have caught that in the docs.  (I also thought the lambda expression should have worked.  ``ex`` is definitely defined in the code...maybe it had something to do with the fact I tried it at a ``set_trace`` using the python debugger).